# how to use .onViewAdded with a Constraint Layout

Tags: android, kotlin, event-handling

I have a listener setup to drop an imageview into a constraint layout. And I want to trigger an event when that view is added to the constraint layout. But I can't for the life of me figure out the syntax or how to make the .onViewAdded() event work for me. Do I need to override it and write my own, if so how do I attach it to my constraint layout?

What I'm trying to do right now is something like below, and very obviously wrong. And apparently I'm so off base that I can't even figure out how to google what I'm trying to do correctly. Can someone help me out?

```
myConstraintLayout.onViewAdded {
// do my thing here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to extend `ConstraintLayout`, override `onViewAdded` (don't forget to call `super()`) and then execute the code you want at the end of the overridden `onViewAdded` method.

If you want to know when the views are added outside of the `ConstraintLayout` class then you will also have to create a listener that is invoked every time `onViewAdded()` is called.

You would then create a `registerOnViewAddedListener()` method in your newly extended class to allow other classes to be notified of the changes.

If you want to listen for views being added from the beginning of the application life cycle then you would have to register the listeners before the layout is inflated. Possibly in `OnCreate()`.

I don't write Kotlin but I can give an example in Java if required. Just comment on this post if you would like an example in Java.

You also asked "How do I attach it to my ConstraintLayout?"

You would be extending `ConstraintLayout` and therefore would use your extended version in the XML file.